# android.app что это

Tags: java, android

android.app или android.graphics библиотека? Или хранилище классов? Кто "на пальцах" может объяснить?

Answer (score 1):

**android.app** и **android.graphics** -- это пакеты (packages). Если на пальцах, то пакеты представляют собой именованную совокупность классов (и, возможно, пакетов). Пакеты группируют классы с похожей функциональностью.

Answer (score 0):

Правильней это назвать пакетом (в терминологии Java) с набором классов. При этом внутри пакета могут находиться другие пакеты.

Answer (score 0):

android.app это пакет содержащий высокоуровневые классы предназначенные для описания общей модели андроид приложений. Существует четыре основных компонента для приложений под Андроид использование которых регламентируется функциональностью разрабатываемого приложения: Activity, Service (находятся в пакете android.app ) и  BroadcastReceiver, ContentProvider (находятся в пакете android.content). Также в пакете определяются классы описывающие dialogs, notifications и action bar, которые также могут являться компонентами приложений.

android.graphics это пакет содержащий классы предоставляющие низкоуровневые графические инструменты.